# Crystal Reports XI hangs when opening a report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am trying to open a report in Crystal Report 11 Designer (product version 11.5.8.826), but it seems to freeze up. This report use to work fine, but today the client could not load the report.

I also tried to open the report on another developer's workstation, with the same result.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 7):

In the page setup menu, you can check the No Printer checkbox and it will no longer have the delay of looking for a printer on the network. I find it often useful to start a report against the Microsoft XPS Document Writer Printer or something along those lines though.

Answer (score 6):

We found the answer. We used a program called Wireshark (www.wireshark.org).

We closed down every app, and just ran the wireshark and tried to open the report in the crystal designer.

Then found that it was trying to access the printer spooler service on a box we used, but changed recently to another box. So just restarted the service on the old box, and all is good again

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: I too had this issued. Worked fine on the development environment, but not on the test servers. An 'ExportToPDF' report was searching for a local printer, causing it to hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure all servers referenced in the report are still online? If you've changed database connections on the report, I've seen Crystal store a reference to the old one even when there are no active usages. If the old server is offline, Crystal still tries to connect to it when loading and will hang for a long time. We had a report that used to load in seconds start taking minutes right after an old test server was powered down. Powered it back up, it loaded instantly again, even though all the connections to it were seeming removed. We wound up totally rebuilding the report from scratch.

I found it using Sysinternals TDIMon, it showed connection attempts and timeouts coming from Crystal.

Comment: Similar issue for legacy reports and old non existant servers.  Work around is to make sure you have a connection to a current database.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues open a report and the designer concurrently.

At the time, I didn't have Internet connectivity and the designer was trying (unsuccessfully) to load the web content that is included in the 'Start Page'.  Eventually, the timeout was exceeded and the report loaded.  I unchecked the 'Show online resources'.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem also and tried several items listed here.  Didn't work.  Then I tried opening the file I wanted from within Crystal Reports using the folder icon. The reports opened immediately.  But if I used windows explorer and  went to the folder they were stored in and then tried to open the crystal report it would take 5 minutes to load (3 minutes to load the designer tab, then another 2 minutes to load the preview tab).

Answer (score 0):

try this "C# code":

```
ReportDocument rpDoc = new ReportDocument()
rpDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"reportname.rpt"));
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Crystal Reports 2008 (XII)!
I tryed to stop the Windows printer spooling service while CR was freezed and got instantly an anwer freom CR (Printer not.. blah blah using default...blah)

After that, i removed the 'Printer-checkbox' in page setup (answer above). After that i had no problem loading this Report in CR Designer and also the C# ReportDocument.Load(string filePath) worked fine....

Answer (score 0):

**Crystal Reports are hanging from all windows servers 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5**

Solution:
Selected the printer 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer'.
To do this go to the report in the designer->Design->Page-Setup and select.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue as well and determined that it had to do with the default printer that is attached to the printer when the report is created. Very similar issue and resoltuon to what Pirmin Ruegg encountered. Setting the default printer to one that all users have, or Selecting the No printer option, corrected our issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same is the case with me. My application stucks when i view the report but after checking the "NO PRINTER" option in the crystal report designer it works fine.