# Crystal Reports load depending on its mood

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report viewer on Windows forms.

The report viewer has one report associated with it. I pass 24 parameters programatically. When i try to run the program, sometimes the reports shows and sometimes the software hangs up.

I m passing same data every time to the report. There are no compile time errors. When I do step-debbuging, then every time the report loads perfectly and there are no hang-ups.

What can be reason of this moody opening of report ????

**Edit1:**

During step debugging, I found that assignment of `reportsource` to `CrystalReportViewer` causes the software to hangup.

```
 goldBillReport = new GoldBill();
 crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = goldBillReport; //Hangs after this !!
 SetGoldParameters();
```

**Edit 2**:
I have changed the scenario now, I take simple windows form, add a crystal report viewer to it. Secondly I create a blank crystal report.

Now I write the following lines in form load event of the windows form which contains viewer.

```
goldBillReport = new BillReport();
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = goldBillReport ;
```

80% of times when I load the form it shows the blank report (as required). The remaining time it shows nothing and application just hangs. Why ?

Note: My real application is very large. Is it the problem that the program is not getting proper memory space to open the report. If yes then are there any ways to collect garbage ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Funny thing about computers, they don't do things based on mood, if they [dis]like you, or the weather. There's something else (though intermittent) causing the problem (maybe database concurrent client/connection limit for a SQLEXPRESS box?).

Comment: @Brad - You're probably right, but my experience with Crystal suggests the OP may be on to something... =)

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code to see where the hang up maybe?

Comment: @Yuck: I hear ya, that's why I "persuaded" my bosses to go the route of SSRS _very_ quickly. Heck, I was even drawing up ASP.NET/PHP report pages just to avoid writing a Crystal report.

Comment: This is a feature of crystal reports.

Comment: @Brad Christie: I ofcourse know that it won't be on mood. It was just a question presented in a lighter sense.

Comment: @Mark: I already mentioned "When I do step-debbuging, then every time the report loads perfectly and there are no hang-ups."

Comment: @Niraj :In page setup menu try to toggle the No Printer checkbox

Comment: @V4Vendetta: I tried that too, but doesn't improve. I would like you to see the Edit part which I recently updated. Thanks

Comment: @Niraj: Maybe this link might help you out, the OP was able to troubleshoot using *Wireshark*. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197782/crystal-reports-xi-hangs-when-opening-a-report)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Wireshark is used if database is on network. Mine is a standalone application.

Answer (score 2):

I would check that you are correctly disposing of your viewer when the form is closed.

Also, I had an issue where the first time I ran a report it was extremely slow. The solution to this was to load a temp report during Application startup (behind a splash screen). This ensured that the Crystal Report DLL's were fully loaded before the user can generate a report. After I did this the reports loaded in few seconds each time.